# onbeforeunload in IE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onbeforeunload

I have some problem:

I am opening new window by javascript:

```
var w = window.open( 'some URL' );
```

and I want to catch event when this window will close. I use onbeforeunload :

```
w.onbeforeunload  =  function(){
//some code
}
```

Also i tried jQuery:

```
$(w).bind('beforeunload' , function(){ 
//some code
});
```

But this event handlers doesn't work in IE 10.  Can somebody advise me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use $(window) instead of your  $(w)

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
            return 'BLAHBLAH!';
        });
```

works fine even in IE10!

if its in the same domain try this:

```
var x = window.open('MYURL');
x.document.write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.onbeforeunload  = function({return 'test';}</script>");
```

Comment: I don't need to catch close event for main window. I need to catch close event for window which i open by code:  var w = window.open( 'some URL' );

Comment: the code has to be executed from the opened url! is the url you open not yours?

Comment: it's my, but i can't make some changes in it. And still it's working fine in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: is the url of the popup in the same domain?

Comment: Yes, in the same domain.